# Shared Memory in cuda fortran not working as expected

Tags: cuda, fortran, gpu, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

I am writing code in CUDA Fortran and a strange behavior occurs. I don't really understand why my code runs like this and would appreciate your help.

It seems that the value 0 is never assigned and even the loops
executes beyond the boarders.

I tried to put the if condition after the loops but it did not help either.
Thank you for your help

```
real, shared :: s_d_aaa_adk(0:15,0:15)
real, shared :: s_d_bbb_adk(0:15,0:15)
real, shared :: s_d_ccc_adk(0:15,0:15)
    
d_k = (blockIdx%x-1)
s_d_j = threadIdx%x-1
s_d_l = threadIdx%y-1   
        
if(d_k == kmax-1)then
    s_d_aaa_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l)  = 0 
    s_d_bbb_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l) = 0
    s_d_ccc_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l)  = 0       
endif
    
do d_k = 0, kmax-2              
    s_d_bbb_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l) = d_bbb(s_d_j,d_l,d_k+1)
    s_d_ccc_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l)  = d_ccc(d_j,s_d_l,d_k+1) 
    s_d_aaa_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l) = d_aaa(d_j,s_d_l,d_k+1)               
end do
```

I set all global memory array sizes to be `(16,16, kmax)`,
the grid is `(128,1,1)`, the block is `(16,16,1)`, and
the kernel is launched as `testkernell<<<grid,block>>>()`

Comment: what is the value of `kmax` ?

Comment: I am slicing a 3d to 2d array through z. kmax is the maximum of z. I want to put each slice in one block.

Comment: It may not be necessary to use a do-loop in that case. What is the size of the 3d array in x,y,z ?

Comment: The size is (64,64,32).The example I post is not the full size because I wanted to see first how it behaves with small arrays. This is why I posted (16,16,4). All 3 arrays are of the same size.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're conditioning the if statement on `d_k`, which is derived from the block index:

```
d_k = (blockIdx%x-1)
if(d_k == kmax-1)then
```

This means that only one block out of the 128 in your grid will actually execute the if statement, setting those particular shared memory values to zero.   Most of your blocks will not execute what's inside the if statement.

And if `kmax` happens to be greater than 128, then none of your blocks will execute the if statement.

If you want that if-statement to be executed within every threadblock, you will need to condition it on something other than the block index.

I would make a suggestion about how to restructure the code, but it's not clear to me what you want to achieve as far as loading data into shared memory.  For instance, your do-loop doesn't make much sense to me:

```
do d_k = 0, kmax-2              
    s_d_bbb_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l) = d_bbb(s_d_j,d_l,d_k+1)
    s_d_ccc_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l)  = d_ccc(d_j,s_d_l,d_k+1) 
    s_d_aaa_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l) = d_aaa(d_j,s_d_l,d_k+1)               
end do            ^     ^
                  |     |
         a given thread has specific values for these indices
```

Your `s_d_j` and `s_d_l` variables are thread indices.  So a given thread will see this do loop, and it will execute the loop iteratively, loading successive values from the various global memory arrays (`d_bbb`, `d_ccc`, etc.) into the *exact same* locations in each shared memory array.

It seems to me you don't really understand how thread execution works.  Pretend that you are a given thread, assign specific values to `s_d_j` and `s_d_l` (and `d_k`, although you are overwriting the block index when re-use that variable as your loop index, which also seems strange to me), and then see if your code execution makes sense.

**EDIT**: Based on additional comments:

You have stated your overall data set size (x,y,z) is (64,64,32).
You have stated "I am slicing ... array through z.  ... I want to put each slice in one block"

That would suggest to me that you should launch one block per slice.  Or maybe you have an algorithm in mind that has multiple blocks assigned to a single slice.  Regardless, I will assume that you want all the slice data (64, 64) available to a given block that is assigned to that slice.  I will assume for now that you will launch 32 blocks.  It should not be difficult to extend to the case where multiple blocks are working on a single slice.  I will also assume a 32x32 thread block rather than 16x16 that you have indicated.  It should not be difficult to extend this to use 16x16 if you want to.

You might do something like this then:

```
real, shared :: s_d_aaa_adk(0:63,0:63)
real, shared :: s_d_bbb_adk(0:63,0:63)
real, shared :: s_d_ccc_adk(0:63,0:63)

c above uses 48KB of shared mem, so assuming cc 2.0+ and cache config set accordingly

d_k = (blockIdx%x-1)
s_d_j = threadIdx%x-1
s_d_l = threadIdx%y-1   

c fill first quadrant
s_d_bbb_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l) = d_bbb(s_d_j,s_d_l,d_k+1)
s_d_ccc_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l) = d_ccc(s_d_j,s_d_l,d_k+1) 
s_d_aaa_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l) = d_aaa(s_d_j,s_d_l,d_k+1)
c fill second quadrant
s_d_bbb_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l) = d_bbb(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l,d_k+1)
s_d_ccc_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l) = d_ccc(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l,d_k+1) 
s_d_aaa_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l) = d_aaa(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l,d_k+1)
c fill third quadrant
s_d_bbb_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = d_bbb(s_d_j,s_d_l+blockDim%y,d_k+1)
s_d_ccc_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = d_ccc(s_d_j,s_d_l+blockDim%y,d_k+1) 
s_d_aaa_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = d_aaa(s_d_j,s_d_l+blockDim%y,d_k+1)
c fill fourth quadrant
s_d_bbb_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = d_bbb(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l+blockDim%y,d_k+1)
s_d_ccc_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = d_ccc(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l+blockDim%y,d_k+1) 
s_d_aaa_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = d_aaa(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l+blockDim%y,d_k+1)


c just guessing about what your intent was on filling with zeroes
c this just makes sure that one of the slices at the end gets zeroes
c instead of the values from the global arrays

if(d_k == kmax-1)then
c fill first quadrant
    s_d_bbb_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l) = 0
    s_d_ccc_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l) = 0
    s_d_aaa_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l) = 0
c fill second quadrant
    s_d_bbb_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l) = 0
    s_d_ccc_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l) = 0
    s_d_aaa_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l) = 0
c fill third quadrant
    s_d_bbb_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = 0
    s_d_ccc_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = 0
    s_d_aaa_adk(s_d_j,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = 0
c fill fourth quadrant
    s_d_bbb_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = 0
    s_d_ccc_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = 0
    s_d_aaa_adk(s_d_j+blockDim%x,s_d_l+blockDim%y) = 0     
endif
```

Comment: Thank you Robert. I am trying to work as new on CUDA. I understand that I should not loop other the blockId now. I have a 3D array (x,y,z) and want to extract plane (x,y) for each z and put these values in shared memory.

Comment: Robert, This is really kind of you. Thank you for taking your time to explain this in detail. It is very clear now.I will implement to my code and let you know.  You are right I have an algorithm which will present many thread blocks per slice. The last target will be to port it to a multi gpu environment.

Comment: Actually it occurs to me that you probably won't be able to use all 48KB of shared memory, as the system uses a small part of it (usually a few bytes) for housekeeping purposes.  So the code as I have written it still won't work.  You don't have enough shared memory to make all the data of a single slice available to each block, so you will have to consider your algorithm and if you can work with a reduced set in shared memory, or else operate some portion of it out of global memory.

Comment: Thank you Robert. But the 48KB is per SM right? In this case lunching the kernels multiple times should help solve the issue of the memory. I was also thinking about stream to overlap the the sending and processing.

Comment: Yes, it's 48KB per SM.  Using streams to overlap the data copy with the compute is a good idea.

Comment: So that is about 4 megabytes. Each M2090 has 6 gigabytes. You won't have a problem fitting 50 of those arrays in global memory. They won't fit in shared memory so you'll have to see if you can work on a subset of the data and still get useful work done and take advantage of data reuse. But perhaps you should start by getting things working out of global memory first.

Comment: Thank you Robert. It seems to me that the shared memory might be very challenging. I am dealing with a modified version of the FDTD algorithm with 50 arrays of size (200,64,1000). I also have 4GPU M2090. So basically I will have about 1GB of each global memory used per each GPU. as starting point I will use 1GPU. If you have some advice i will appreciate because I dont want to have such a data reuse algorithm and deal with the globabl memory only

Comment: The first idea coming to me now will be to iterate in the kernel through each z, load the data in shared memory, compute and write back to global memory (4bytes * 200*64 = 51200 bytes). I dont know if this is the best though.